# Como faço para remover uma pasta do histórico do Git?

Tags: git

Comecei há algum tempo a desenvolver uma página web, que está bem organizada, tem pastas para tudo, exemplo da raiz do repositório/projecto:

```
account/  
products/  
js/  
css/  
img/   
data/ *(pdfs e zips para download)*  
index.php   
etc...
```

O problema é que inicialmente não fazia ideia do problema que os ficheiros binários representavam para o **Git**, e todos ficheiros para download *(pdfs e zips)* no site foram adicionados sucessivamente com vários commits à pasta `data`.

Neste momento o repositório tem **600 Mb**, e sei que caso a pasta data não tivesse sido adicionada teria menos de 10 Mb!

Há alguma maneira de **apagar** permanentemente de todo o histórico do Git uma **pasta** ou por **tipos de ficheiro**, *pdf*, *zip*?

Comment: relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/485278/como-remover-um-arquivo-do-git-mas-o-manter-localmente

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Carece de testes, mas, nesse [link](http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/) é mencionado o seguinte comando para remover arquivos permanentemente do histórico:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch nome_do_arquivo" HEAD
```

Comment: depois de responder vi isso... o problema é mais complexo. Encontrei isso [aqui](http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/). Mas precisaria testar pra ter certeza

Comment: O `filter-branch` é a forma de fazer isso sim. Eu acrescentaria o `--prune-empty`, que vai remover commits que fiquem "vazios" (pois os arquivos que eles alteravam não fazem mais parte do repositório).

Comment: Alias, remova sua resposta original e deixe só o update. :)

Comment: Fiz o teste e o repositório de facto ficou reduzido a 60% do tamanho original. Este não era o valor esperado, de qualquer modo já melhorou ...

Answer (score 19):

As respostas todas estão corretas mas... o que está acontecendo afinal?

Os comandos o git as vezes podem não ser muito amigáveis, aí vai uma explicação *mais humana*.

Utilizando como base o [script do link fornecido pelo @Guilherme](http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/):

```js
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch $files" HEAD
```

## git filter-branch --index-filter "[comando]" HEAD

Aqui estamos passando revisão por revisão instruindo o git a executar nosso comando (que no caso deleta os arquivos).

- [`git filter-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html): Rescreve o histórico, revisão a revisão, conforme os filtros que você especificar.
- `--index-filter`: Esse filtro instrui o git a aplicar o comando *diretamente* no repositório sem fazer uma cópia local, para que o git faça uma cópia local (isto é, realize um *checkout* dos arquivos) utilize `--tree-filter`. A vantagem do `--index-filter` é que sua execução é mais rápida; a desvantagem é que apenas comandos do git podem ser aplicados.
- `"[comando]"`: Aqui vai o comando que o git irá aplicar para cada revisão do repositório.
- `HEAD`: Indica de onde o git deve começar a iterar aplicando o comando. Pode ser outro especificador, como um SHA1 ou uma tag. Basta utilizar `git rev-list` para ver quais as revisões o git utilizará (esse é o comando que ele utiliza internamente).

## git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch [arquivos]

Este é o comando da deleção dos arquivos em si, executado a cada revisão passada pelo *filter-branch*.

- [`git rm`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html): Remove os arquivos do *index* e da cópia de trabalho (no nosso caso, do *index*).
- `-rf`: `-r` de *recursive*, remove os diretórios de forma recursiva. `-f` de *force*, força a remoção do arquivo mesmo se houver modificações locais; não fará diferença no nosso caso, mas também não machuca :-)
- `--cached`: Faz com que o comando trabalhe só sobre o *stage*.
- `--ignore-unmatch`: Não retorna erro (retorno do comando `0`) mesmo se não encontrar os arquivos. Importante pois se o comando utilizado pelo *filter-branch* tiver um retorno diferente de zero o git entende que houve um erro e termina a execução.
- `[arquivos]`: Caminho dos arquivos a serem removidos.

---

Pronto, após executado o comando o arquivo não aparece em nenhuma revisão do histórico do git (`git log`). Então o repositório diminuiu consideravelmente de tamanho? Não exatamente; pelo menos não na sua cópia local.

Ao repassar revisão por revisão excluindo os arquivos o git gerou novas revisões sem os arquivos, e trocando as referências das antigas pelas novas. O que acontece é que quando o git faz isso ele não deleta a revisão completamente do repositório, ele apenas *dereferencia* (nem existe essa palavra né :p) essas revisões: elas continuam existindo no repositório, mesmo orfãs. Você pode averiguar isso listando-as com `git reflog` ou até mesmo verificando o tamanho da pasta `.git` (que continuará ocupando um grande espaço no seu caso).

Para remover completamente essas revisões do git deve-se utilizar a última (e esquecida) linha do script que utilizamos de exemplo:

```js
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ && git reflog expire --expire=now --all &&  git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Vamos lá.

## rm -rf .git/ref/original/

Apagando o backup feito pelo *filter-branch*.

- `rm -rf`: Comando do próprio shell. Novamente `-r` de *recursive*, para apagar subdiretórios; `-f` de *force*, ignora arquivos não existentes e não faz nenhum *prompt* com o usuário.
- `.git/refs/original/`: Essa é a pasta com o backup das referências afetadas pelo comando *filter-branch*.

## git reflog expire --expire=now --all

*Dereferenciando* de vez as revisões orfãs do git.

O *reflog* é, em minha opnião, um dos comandos mais mal documentados (e confusos) de todo o git.

- [`git reflog`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html): Similar ao comando `git log` (contração de *reference log*), só que abrangendo também revisões orfãs, *stashes*, etc.
- `expire`: *Expira* as revisões (remove suas referências do *reflog*, *desconhecendo-as* pelo git).
- `--expire=now`: Considerar revisões a partir de uma data; `now` para aplicar em todas independente do tempo.
- `--all`: Faz com que o *reflog* seja mais abrangente, passando em outros *branches* e *stashes*.

## git gc --aggressive --prune=now

E, finalmente, apagando-as.

- [`git gc`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html): git *garbage collector*. Remove arquivos e comprime objetos do git
- `--aggressive`: Faz com que o git realize a otimização mesmo que o comando demore a ser executado.
- `--prune=now`: Considera objetos a partir de uma data. `now` para aplicar em todos independente do tempo.

---

## Lembre-se, você rescreveu seu histórico

Para aplicar seu histórico local, agora modificado, a seu remoto você terá que *forçar* seu push:

```
git push -f
```

Considere os efeitos dessa rescrita para quem também estiver trabalhando sobre o mesmo remoto que você.

---

## p.s.

- Há uma adaptação minha na última linha do script que limpa o histórico repositório. A diferença é a inclusão do paramêtro `--expire=now` e `--prune=now`. Se não utilizado estes paramêtros o git assume um tempo default de 90 dias e 2 semanas respectivamente, funcionando assim apenas em suas revisões mais antigas.
- O GitHub também possui [tutorial bem semelhante](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente para mim. Em resumo (pois a resposta é bem extensa), faça o comando: `git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch $files" HEAD` e então: `rm -rf .git/refs/original/ && git reflog expire --expire=now --all &&  git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

Comment: EXCELENTE resposta

Comment: Ótima explicação. Ainda estou receoso de executar por ter mais pessoas trabalhando no mesmo projeto

Answer (score 3):

Adaptando o comando indicado no [cap. 9.7 do livro Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/Git-Internamente-Manuten%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-Recupera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-Dados):

```sh
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch nome-do-arquivo-ou-diretorio'
```

Note que, como o comando reescreve o histórico, será preciso baixar (clonar) o repositório novamente em todos os computadores que já tinham uma cópia do repositório.

Explicação do livro:

> A opção `--index-filter` é semelhante à opção `--tree-filter` utilizada no Capítulo 6, exceto que em vez de passar um comando que modifica os arquivos que você fez check-out no disco, você está modificando sua área de seleção (staging area) ou índice.
>
> Em vez de remover um arquivo específico com algo como rm file, você tem que removê-lo com git `rm --cached` — você deve removê-lo do índice, não do disco. A razão para fazê-lo desta maneira é a velocidade — porque o Git não precisa fazer o check out de cada revisão no disco antes de executar o seu filtro, o processo pode ser muito mais rápido.
>
> A opção `--ignore-unmatch` do `git rm` diz a ele para não mostrar erros se o padrão que você está tentando remover não estiver lá.
>
> Seu histórico já não contém uma referência para o arquivo. No entanto, seu reflog e um novo conjunto de refs que o git adicionou quando você fez o filter-branch em .git/refs/original ainda não, então você tem que removê-los e, em seguida, fazer um repack do banco de dados. Você precisa se ​​livrar de qualquer coisa que tenha um ponteiro para aqueles commits antigos antes de fazer o repack:
>
> `$ rm -Rf .git/refs/original`
>
> `$ rm -Rf .git/logs/`
>
> `$ git gc`

Comment: Para diretórios deve-se usar `... 'git rm -r ...'`. Algumas flags adicionais seriam `--prune-empty` para remover qualquer commit que ficar em branco (se for desejável), `--tag-name-filter cat` para preservar qualquer *tag* que exista no repositório e terminar com `-- --all` para aplicar em todas as *refs*.