# Deletar pastas no Github

Tags: github

Commitei meu projeto no github e depois de um tempo, algumas pastas não precisariam estar mais ali. Eu tenho conhecimento que dá para deletar manualmente no github, porém para isso acontecer, preciso deletar arquivo por arquivo para a pasta sumir.

A situação é essa:
Quando eu criei meu projeto, existiam as pastas Landing e Email, mas como não preciso mais dessas pastas, criei a pasta img e unifiquei os arquivos dentro dessa pasta. Quando alterei e subi o projeto novamente, a pasta img apareceu corretamente, porém as pastas Landing e Email não sumiram, mesmo tendo usado o git rm e deletando-as. Pelo git status aparece que elas foram deletadas, mas no meu repositório no github elas ainda aparecem.

Existe outra maneira de deletar, não sendo manualmente no github?

Comment: Viu esse tópico? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/583/como-faço-para-remover-uma-pasta-do-histórico-do-git

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Bem vamos lá:

1. Primeiro certifique-se que o seu repositório está sincronizado com o repositório remoto: `$ git pull origin master`, (supondo que o branch seja master).
2. Então remova a pasta localmente: `$ git rm -r Landing Email`.
3. Agora faça um commit das modificações: `$ git commit -m "Remove pastas Landing e Email"`
4. Sincronize com repositório remoto: `$ git push origin master`

Após essas mudanças o repositório remoto deve estar sem as pastas Landing e Email.

Comment: Olá Walker :)

Testei aqui e funcionou, te agradeço.

Comment: Show de bola. 4 anos depois e funcional.