# Como eu removo um commit do histórico?

Tags: git, github

Nos primeiros commits versionei a senha do meu e-mail, agora subi um arquivo .dist sem essa senha, porém queria remover do histórico de commits o arquivo que tinha a minha senha.

Isso é possível?

Se eu navegar no github nos históricos dos meus commits, consigo visualizar a versao antiga com a senha.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como faço para remover uma pasta do histórico do Git?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/583/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-remover-uma-pasta-do-hist%c3%b3rico-do-git)

Comment: João, achei esse site que talvez te ajude: https://brorlandi.github.io/git-desfazendo-commits

Answer (score 0):

**Descobri qual era o commit que eu queria voltar:**

```
git log
```

**Voltei para um anterior do que eu havia versionado:**

```
git reset (hash do commit)
```

**Caso deseje também que sejam desfeitas as alterações no arquivo:**

```
git reset (hash commit) --hard
```

Como eu não queria perder o conteúdo não utilizei o --hard

**Retirando o commit do GitHub**

```
git push --force
```