# Como remover um arquivo do Git, mas o manter localmente?

Tags: git, github

Quando tenho um arquivo no meu computador local que gostaria que não fosse upado para o repositório no GitHub, eu simplesmente crio um arquivo `.gitignore` e adiciono o *path* do arquivo. Ocorre que eu gostaria de remover um arquivo do repositório no GitHub, mas mantê-lo no meu computador local.

Em outras palavras, eu gostaria que o arquivo fosse ignorado depois dele ter feito parte de *commits* anteriores.

O que tentei fazer foi:

1. Deletar o arquivo no repositório do GitHub;
2. Adicionar o path do arquivo no `.gitignore` no meu computador local;
3. Fazer um `push`.

Bom, isso não funcionou, já que o `push` falhou e pediu para que eu fizesse um `pull` antes. Ora, fazer o `pull` atualiza meu diretório local e remove o arquivo que eu gostaria de manter. Tem uma forma de descontinuar um arquivo em um repositório Git?

Comment: Relacionado: [Como faço para remover uma pasta do histórico do Git?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/583/100416)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não precisa de sequer mexer pela interface do GitHub. Dá para fazer tudo localmente. Basicamente, há de se utilizar o comando `git rm`:

O problema é que, ao utilizar o `git rm` "sozinho", o arquivo será removido do índice do Git **e** da árvore de trabalho. O problema é que só queremos remover o arquivo do índice do Git, mantendo-o localmente.

Para isso, a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached) sugere o uso da *flag* `--cached`:

> Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

Portanto, o que você precisa é:

```
git rm --cached filename.ext
```

Uma vez que fez isso, pode inclusive adicionar o nome do arquivo ao `.gitignore`, para prevenir futuras adições.