# Apagar uma pasta do GIT quando estiver ultrapassado 10Gb no projeto

Tags: git, gitlab

Fui realizar um commit em um projeto meu e foi apresentado a mensagem que ultrapassou o limite do projeto de 10Gb, porém, não consegui excluir uma pasta e seus arquivos no git bash e nem diretamente no gitlab. Vi informações que ao excluir os arquivos diretamente no gitlab automaticamente a pasta será excluída, mas tenho mais de 200 arquivos dentro da pasta para excluir, eu quero excluir as pastas que estão acima do limite permitido pelo git.

Mensagem do GIT:

> remote: GitLab: Your push has been rejected, because this repository has exceeded its size limit of 10 GB by 33 MB. Please contact your GitLab administrator for more information.

Comment: Entendi o problema, mas qual seria a pergunta? Como podemos ajudar?

Comment: esses arquivos são necessários para o funcionamento da aplicação? Adicionar esta pasta no arquivo `.gitignore` seria uma solução para você?

Comment: Pelo que entendi vc só quer remover o diretório do git, sem remover do projeto: veja o comando `git rm -r --cached /path`, doc:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached

Comment: já copiei a pasta e os arquivos para outro local, não é necessário na aplicação, podendo ser removido do projeto

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como remover um arquivo do Git, mas o manter localmente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/485278/como-remover-um-arquivo-do-git-mas-o-manter-localmente)

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/), um repo git grande assim não é muito recomendável. Dependendo do cenário, eu consideraria até reescrever o histórico colocando esse arquivos grandes em LFS.