# Como listar todos os arquivos que já foram "trackeados" ao menos uma vez pelo git?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, gitlab

Geralmente, uso o comando abaixo para listar todos os arquivos que estão atualmente sendo mapeados pelo git, para uma branch específica (`develop` por exemplo):

```
git ls-tree -r develop
```

Uso muito esse comando para saber quais arquivos (desnecessários ou sensíveis) preciso remover do git para não subir ao repositório remoto.

As minhas dúvidas:

- É possível, através desse comando base ou de algum outro, listar todos os arquivos que já foram ao menos uma vez *trackeados* pelo git e que posteriormente foram removidos em algum commit, para que eu possa [removê-los do histórico do git](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/583/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-remover-uma-pasta-do-hist%C3%B3rico-do-git).
- É possível listar e remover do histórico um arquivo que já foi *trackeado* ao menos uma vez de todas as branchs atualmente existentes?

Comment: com certeza é possível, pois é possível re-escrever a história do git. Uma vez em um projeto que participei, foi necessário excluir dados sensíveis de um repositório git, essa foi a ferramenta que utilizamos: [bfg](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). Também existe uma página do github com [instruções](https://docs.github.com/pt/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) de como fazer isso via um comando `git filter-repo`. É algo assim que está procurando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos listar arquivos que já foram *trackeados* e posteriormente removidos, utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A | sort -u
```

Em um projeto pessoal, eu executei o comando no terminal e obtive na listagem o arquivo `.env` que tinha commitado por acidente em um dos commits iniciais, mas que foi posteriormente removido e adicionando ao `.gitignore`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora uma explicação detalhada de algumas partes do comando acima faz:

- `--pretty=format:`: Este parâmetro especifica o formato em que você deseja que o log apareça. Não passamos nenhum argumento, o que significa que não queremos nenhuma informação adicional além dos nomes dos arquivos.
- `--name-only`: Este parâmetro especifica que desejamos ver somente o nome dos arquivos, sem nenhum outro detalhe ou informação adicional.
- `--diff-filter=A`: Este parâmetro especifica que desejamos ver somente arquivos adicionados ao repositório. O valor `A` significa adicionado (`added`), commits que adicionam arquivos;
- `| sort -u`: O "pipe" (`|`) redireciona a saída do comando anterior para a entrada deste comando. O `sort -u` irá classificar e remover duplicatas de todos os nomes de arquivos listados.

Existem outros valores interessantes para uso no comando `--diff-filter=`, como `D` para os removidos (`deleted`), `C` para commits que realizam operações de merge, etc... Veja mais [aqui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203). Podemos usar mais de um valor ao mesmo tempo, separando-os por uma vírgula, para exibir vários tipos de commits ao mesmo tempo, por exemplo: `--diff-filter=A,M` exibirá tanto os commits que adicionam quanto os que modificam arquivos.

---

> É possível listar e remover do histórico um arquivo que já foi
> trackeado ao menos uma vez de todas as branchs atualmente existentes?

...ainda vou fazer uma pesquisa e vê se existe uma solução. Em breve edito minha resposta.

Answer (score -4):

git ls-tree --full-tree --name-only -r HEAD

--full-tree makes the command run as if you were in the repo's root directory.

-r recurses into subdirectories. Combined with --full-tree this gives you all committed, tracked files.

--name-only removes SHA / permission info for when you just want the file paths.
HEAD specifies which branch you want the list of tracked, committed files for. HEAD is the pointer for the commit you have checked out currently.